# Porque al cerrar el modal el boton tiene cursor

Tags: javascript, html, modal

Tengo un problema con mi modal, después de insertar un dato queda se bloquea mi pagina y pone un cursor en el botón donde no debería estar, no se si sea un div que no se cerre  o que pone algo de mas que me esta gererando problemas

Adjunto codigo HTML

```
<!--Container -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2 offset-10">
            <div class="text-center">
                <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalUsuario" id="btnAgregar" > 
                    <i class="bi bi-plus-circle-fill"></i> Crear Usuario
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><br>

    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="datos_usuario" class="table table-sm">
            <thead class="tbl-users-head">
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Nombre </th>
                    <th>Apellidos</th>
                    <th>Departamento</th>
                    <th>Usuario</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Imagen</th>
                    <th>Editar</th>
                    <th>Eliminar</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class = "tbl-users-body">
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalUsuario" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-secondary">
                <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel" style="color:white;">Crear Usuario</h1>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>

            <form method="POST" id="formulario" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label for="imagen_usuario">Selecciona una imagen</label>
                                <input type="file" name="imagen_usuario" id="imagen_usuario" class="form-control"><br>
                                <div>
                                    <span class = "img_formUser"  id="imagen_subida"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                                <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Completa el campo..." required><br>
                                <label for="usuario">Usuario</label>
                                <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" class="form-control" placeholder="Completa el campo..." required><br>
                                <label for="contrasena">Contraseña</label>
                                <input type="text" name="contrasena" id="contrasena" class="form-control" placeholder="Completa el campo..." required><br>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label for="apellidos">Apellidos</label>
                                <input type="text" name="apellidos" id="apellidos" class="form-control" placeholder="Completa el campo..." required><br>
                                <label for="departamento">Departamento</label>
                                <input type="text" name="departamento" id="departamento" class="form-control" placeholder="Completa el campo..." required><br>
                                <label for="email">Correo</label>
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Completa el campo..." required><br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id_usuario" id="id_usuario">
                        <input type="hidden" name="operacion" id="operacion">
                        <input type="hidden" name="img_user" id="img_user">
                        <input type="hidden" name="idRow" id="idRow">
                        <input  name="action" id="action" class="btn btn-success" value="Crear" >
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<script src="../lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../lib/bootstrap-5.2.1-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../lib/bootstrap-5.2.1-dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="../lib/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11/dist/sweetalert2.min.js"></script> -->

<script src="../js/usuarios.js"></script>
```

}

Adjunto la imagen en el Boton donde dice crear usuario, me pone un cursor para poner letras pero no es un input en el cual yo deba escribir ademas de que me bloquea el scroll, si no hasta que actualice o pulse varias veces el mismo modal se vuelve a "activar" la pagina

[image: Adjunto imagen]

Comment: Ya pude encontrar mi error era un error de version de Bootstrap en la linea del boton, no va data-bs-toggle, solo va data-toggle